# Nothing showing in the installation field parse.com obj-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, installation

Nothing seems to be showing when I run the app on my phone. Even when I delete the cache. My code seems fine. I don't know how to solve this. I've tried adding channels, reseting the simulator, and even deleteing the app from the phone. What can I do to make this work?

Here's my code for the AppDelegate.m file:

```
#import "ParseExampleAppDelegate.h"

@implementation ParseExampleAppDelegate


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    [[UITabBar appearance] setSelectedImageTintColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];


    [Parse setApplicationId:@"deletedforsecurity"
                  clientKey:@"deletedforsecurity"];


    // Register for Push Notitications, if running iOS 8
    if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) {
        UIUserNotificationType userNotificationTypes = (UIUserNotificationTypeAlert |
                                                        UIUserNotificationTypeBadge |
                                                        UIUserNotificationTypeSound);
        UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:userNotificationTypes
                                                                                 categories:nil];
        [application registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
        [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
    } else {
        // Register for Push Notifications before iOS 8
        [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge |
                                                         UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert |
                                                         UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];
    }


    return YES;


}


- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
    // Store the deviceToken in the current installation and save it to Parse.
    PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
    [currentInstallation setDeviceTokenFromData:deviceToken];
    currentInstallation.channels = @[ @"global" ];
    [currentInstallation saveInBackground];
}
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
    [PFPush handlePush:userInfo];
}

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}

@end
```

I appreciate any help, and thank you.

Comment: Have you deleted the installation in question from the backend?

Comment: Nope, the class '_Installation' in Parse.com hasn't been deleted, @soulshined.

Comment: not the class, just the row of the installation

Comment: What do you mean @soulshined ?

Comment: Here. I've added a hosted image so you could see what the table looks like. Take a look: http://s24.postimg.org/4z9azg8np/Screen_Shot_2015_03_15_at_18_55_27.png !

Comment: Yeah i know what it looks like, I'm asking because if you delete a row from the installation Class in the past its not going to show up again if you have deleted the app and reinstalled it

Comment: Try incrementing your build number by 1 so if your build number is 1.2 increment it to 1.2.1 so a fresh installation id will populate. Then let me know what happens

Comment: @soulshined where do I change my build number?

Answer (score 0):

Based on our conversation in the comments;

With Parse backend, it's highly likely that you have deleted an installation row from the Installation class at one point in time. Using Parse, if you have deleted a installation id it will retain that state until you create a new app version, or alter a field in the installation class, so the next time the user opens the app a new installation id will populate.

All you have to do is change a version of something in the Installation class and the new field will populate:

I recommended incrementing the build number by 1. You can do this by the following :

[image: pic1]

I would recommend you not delete installation rows unless you are **1000%** sure you don't need it

Comment: this doesn\t work. I've changed the version number and build to 3.0 but still there is no change. The _Installation calss is left blank. Is something wrong with my code?

Comment: No, unless your not using the proper application or clientKeys but since you said you've successfully deleted one. Incrementing the build number works every time all the time for me

Comment: I've tested it on my iPhone 5. I've ran the app, registered a user, etc. But it still won't show.

Comment: Then you have something else going on, I can't really say from this perspective @armanb21 altering the build number is a successful fix

Comment: do you have any idea on how I could solve something like this? Or any approaches to solving the problem as well.

Comment: @armanb21 if it's a project you haven't invested any time in, you could just create a new project - other than that I don't have any ideas other than a simple Clean build.

Comment: @armanb21 Parse dosen't count new installs from a device that's already been registered (including the simulator) so by deleting them they won't register as a new install unless otherwise altered as stated above.

Comment: @armanb21 you could alternatively create a new app in Parse.com and just use those API & client Keys in your iOS project that would create a new fresh Parse.com app, thats the route i would take

Comment: That's a good idea. I'm going to try that and I'll let you know how it goes in the end.

Comment: do you know if it is possible to export all the push notification and email settings from one app to another on Parse.com because I need to do that when I create a new app in Parse.

Comment: what do you mean export push notification and email settings @armanb21

Comment: for my push notifications I have to add settings and also when a user forgets their passowrd Parse's API needs a bunch of stuff to forward to my domain, etc. Thanks for your help, Arman.

Comment: I got an error! I just haven't had the console open: this is the error: application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3000 "no valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application" UserInfo=0x14e80af0 {NSLocalizedDescription=no valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application}